# delete entire row in excel based on value c#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, vsto

i am creating add-in in excel to delete the selected range where the values is greater than 0 , but currently if more continuous cells contains greater than 0 values , it is deleting only 1 & 3 values(odd rows) and leaving the rest , kindly guide me how to delete all the rows contains the value more than 0.

first table:
[image: First table]

after first click:
[image: After one click]

desired :
[image: desired output]

code:

```
private void btncalc_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Worksheet activeworksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;

            Range usedRange = activeworksheet.UsedRange;

            foreach (Excel.Range r in usedRange)
            {
                // check condition:
                if (r.Value2 > 0.0F)
                {
                    // if match, delete and shift remaining cells up:
                    r.EntireRow.Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/q/65734209/4961700

Comment: hi thank you for the response ..that is about hiding cells and it is in VBA  , i am already new to c3 i don't know anything about VBA

Answer (score 2):

Consider that each of the rows has indices

| Row Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 |

Once 1 has been detected as greater than 0 and deleted (index is 1), then the indices will be adjusted

| Row Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 |

the next row index will be at 2, which means that it will look at Value=3 instead of Value=2. Value=2 will be skipped and the row for Value=3 will be deleted

| Row Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 |

now the Row Index=3, which corresponds to the Value just after 4.
The conclusion is the location of the cells will be adjusted with each row deletion while the index being used is being retained.

The **trick** is to store the ranges containing a value > 0 into a `List<Range>`, reverse the `List<Range>` and do the deletion.

```
  private void btncalc_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
        Excel.Worksheet activeworksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
        Range usedRange = activeworksheet.UsedRange;
        List<Range> list= new List<Range>;
        foreach (Excel.Range r in usedRange)
        {
            // check condition:
            if (r.Value2 > 0.0F)
            {
                list.Add(r);
            }
        }
        list.Reverse();
        foreach(var r in list)
        {
             r.EntireRow.Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
        }
    }
```

This is to make sure that the deletion starts at the bottom Rows of the Sheet.

**P.S.** I have not yet tested this approach so there might be some problem with the code, but you get the idea.

**Edit in response to the OP's follow-up question:**

you can also use this code to delete the row

```
  private void btncalc_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
        Excel.Worksheet activeworksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
        Range usedRange = activeworksheet.UsedRange;
        List<Range> list= new List<Range>;
        foreach (Excel.Range r in usedRange)
        {
            // check condition:
            if (r.Value2 > 0.0F)
            {
                list.Add(r);
            }
        }
        list.Reverse();
        foreach(var r in list)
        {
             activeworksheet.Rows[r.Row].Delete();
             //Or
             //int rowNo = r.Row;              
             //Range range = sheet.Cells[rowNo, 1];
             //column A is row 1              
             //range.EntireRow.Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer .. it is successfully removing the values greater than zero. But it is only deleting only when I select column "A" and if I select any other column it is showing error like below: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:                                                            
`'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01A8'`  the error is coming at :
`r.EntireRow.Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);`